# Row data var not found if view has no document

Tags: xpages

I have a view panel where I want to style the color the of text in the row based on a value in the document.

```
<xp:viewPanel id="dataView1" var="rowData" rows="5"
    rowClasses="#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue('objectStatus') == 'Inactive' ? 'status-inactive' : ''}">
```

This works perfectly fine if the view has at least one document, but if the view is empty I get the following error:

> com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
>   Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
>   Script interpreter error,  line=1, col=10: [ReferenceError] 'rowData' not found

I'm guessing it has something to do with `rowData` not being created unless a document exist, but I can't figure out how to check for it.

I tried `if (rowData != null)` and `!@IsNull(rowData)` but I still get the same error.

How do I solve this problem?

(Note that I am late to the XPages game.)

EDIT:

Thanks to all for the input but I was able to solve the issue by simply checking the view count:

```
if (getComponent('dataView1').getRowCount() > 0) {
  'Inactive'.equals(rowData.getColumnValue('objectStatus')) ? 'status-inactive' : ''
}
```

EDIT 2:

Knut has a slightly quicker solution so I gave him credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it with `if (typeof rowData !== 'undefined') ...`.
If the view is empty then rowData is 'undefined'.

```
<xp:viewPanel id="viewPanel1" var="rowData" rows="5"
    rowClasses="#{javascript:  
        if (typeof rowData !== 'undefined')
            rowData.getColumnValue('objectStatus') == 'Inactive' ? 'status-inactive' : ''
    }">
```

(This solution is probably some ms faster than .getRowCount() :-) )

Comment: Ahh thanks. I solved it a different way by checking the view's row count (see my edited post) but I didn't know you could check for 'undefined'. This information will be quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

Knut correctly explains the solution to what you're trying to do. The answer to why it doesn't work is slightly different. `rowData` was an apt name to choose, it's going to be the current row's data. But you're setting a property for the DataView as a whole. What is the current row for the whole DataView? The answer is, there isn't one because you're not dealing with an individual row.

Comment: @Paul Stephen Withers Thanks Paul.  However, please see my response to Knut's comment--calculating classes based on rowData _does_ work.

Comment: Turns out I was able to get around the error simply by checking the view count. I added the solution to my post.

Comment: @Paul: Jorey is right, it is possible to use the row variable `rowData` in `rowClasses` calculation. Therefore I deleted my first answer and replaced it with the 'undefined' solution.